# Storage permission request not working in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to access storage on an Android emulator ***(SDK 33)*** from Flutter.
Here is the code that I'm testing it with:

```
void test() async {
     PermissionStatus storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
     if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
         print("granted");
     }
     if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
         print("denied");
     }
     if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
         openAppSettings();
     }
 }
```

I have included the "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I have tried giving permissions for Camera and it worked, but it doesn't work for storage.

When I check for the storages permission status it is permanently denied, and when app's settings open it says "No permissions requested".

I have tried running "flutter clean" which seems to be necessary when updating the Manifest.

I have tried uninstalling from the phone and reinstalling the app

How do I fix it?

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: `am trying to access storage` No, you are not. You did not post code for that. You mess around with permissions.

Comment: doesn't this do that?
PermissionStatus storageStatus = await Permission.storage.request();

Comment: The android version is 13

Comment: Then you should not ask for READ and WRITE permission anymore.

Comment: What permission am I supposed to ask? I am trying to save files so I assumed it would be WRITE permission.

Comment: Not for Android 13+ devices anymore.

Comment: What do I do then?

Comment: Access the storage. We have no idea what you wanna do.

Comment: I want to save files, to do that i need the permission to access the storage, which I can't get because for some reason when I request the access it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using **Android version 13 (or SDK 33)**, there is no need to request storage permission as the app will have access to the files by default.

So in addition to checking the storage permission, also check if the SDK version is older than 33 by using the [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) library.

```dart
void test() async {
  final plugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  final android = await plugin.androidInfo;

  final storageStatus = android.version.sdkInt < 33
      ? await Permission.storage.request()
      : PermissionStatus.granted;

  if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    print("granted");
  }
  if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    print("denied");
  }
  if (storageStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
    openAppSettings();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus):

```dart
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
```

Further read:

- [Flutter —Storage access for Android SDK 33](https://medium.com/@marcoedomingos/flutter-storage-access-for-android-sdk-33-d19e2b693017)
- [Permission.storage.request() not working on android 13 (SDK 33)](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/995#issuecomment-1476022096)
- [Granular media permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

**once try to do this.**

**Add in your manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**for requesting permission.**

```
Future<bool> requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
  if (await permission.isGranted) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var result = await permission.request();
    if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

**for checking permission also you can change dialog text as per your need**

```
Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    ///For Check permission..
    if (Platform.isAndroid ? !await requestPermission(Permission.storage) && !await requestPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage) : !await requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
      await Get.dialog(CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Photos & Videos permission"),
        content: const Text(" Photos & Videos permission should be granted to connect with device, would you like to go to app settings to give Bluetooth & Location permissions?"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
              child: const Text('No thanks'),
              onPressed: () {
                Get.back();
              }),
          TextButton(
              child: const Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Get.back();
                await openAppSettings();
              })
        ],
      ));
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

[Use like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oRPA.png)

**I hope these things solve your issue.**

Comment: Somehow, this does not work on the emulator. It works on an actual device though. Any ideas why?

Comment: Not working dear, thanks