# Permission to storage denied

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

My app runs fine on Linux but I struggle with android's permission system. Pressing a button, I would like to load a `json` file that is exported from another program. However, I get the error:

```
I/flutter (24500): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)
E/flutter (24500): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)
```

## Setup

### Manifest

I feel like I do not need all these permissions, but I simply tried whether more permissions would fix my issue.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

### Code to grant permission

```dart
Future<void> requestPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    print("Requesting Permission");
    status = await Permission.storage.request();
    print("Again? $status");
    // You might want to check status again here and handle denied permissions accordingly
  } else {
    print("Not requesting Permission!");
  }
}
```

Status returns with access denied and trying to access the file:

```dart
    Future<void> pickFile(parent) async {
      await requestPermission();
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['json'],
      );
      if (result != null) {
        String filePath = result.files.single.path!; // Assuming the file path is not null

        try {
          File file = File(filePath);
          if (await file.exists()) {
            String fileContent = await file.readAsString();
            // Parse the JSON content
            Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(fileContent);
          } else {
            print('File does not exist');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error reading file: $e');
        }
      }
    }
```

fails with:

```
I/flutter (24500): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)
E/flutter (24500): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)
```

## What I have tried

I found multiple related issues:

- https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/995
- [Storage permission request not working in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290497/storage-permission-request-not-working-in-flutter)
- https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/907

But asking for photo, video or audio doesn't suite my needs. "to downgrade your targetSdkVersion to 32" doesn't help, because GooglePlay requires >=33 (but downgrading to 32 does work).

Comment: What is Android version of used device?

Comment: `would like to load a json file that is exported from another program. ` For that you do not need any permission on Android if you use one of the available file pickers.

Comment: Use not only file.exists() but also file.canRead() before...

Comment: You use a very strange file picker which gives you a path. But you cannot read that file from path as it is from another app. This counts for Android 11+ devices.

Comment: The json file is placed in the download folder. It is generated by another app, exported and placed there. I am aware that FilePicker gives me a path. I would be fine with a solution that suggests another Filepicker to avoid the issue you mention with Android 11

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `application` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```xml
<manifest xlmns:android="...">
  <application
    android:label="..."
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    
    <!-- Your manifest stuff here -->

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ask for external storage permission. It has to be done by Android, not by flutter.

you have that problem solved here.

[How to fix Flutter Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138258/how-to-fix-flutter-error-filesystemexception-cannot-open-file/78061009#78061009)